# NHibernate JoinAlias query with null test not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nullreferenceexception, queryover

I'm getting some unexpected behaviour with a JoinAlias QueryOver in NHibernate.

My entity essentially looks like this:

```
public class Field
{
    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Field Parent { get; protected set; }
    public virtual FieldType Type { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; protected set; }

...(Ctors etc
}
```

My mapping is such:

```
public class FieldMap : ClassMap<Field>
{
    public FieldMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();

        References(x => x.Type)
            .Column("FieldTypeId")
            .LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.All()
            ;

        Map(x => x.Value);

        References(x => x.Parent)
            .Column("ParentFieldId")
            .Nullable()
            .LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.All()
            ;
    }
```

My query:

```
        Field fieldAlias = null;
        string typeAlias = null;
        Field parentFieldAlias = null;

        var query = getSession().QueryOver<Field>(() => fieldAlias)
            .JoinAlias(() => fieldAlias.Type, () => typeAlias)
            .Where(() => typeAlias.Name == type)
            .JoinAlias(() => fieldAlias.Parent, () => parentFieldAlias)
            .Where(() => (parentFieldAlias.Value == parentValue) || (parentFieldAlias == null))
            ;
```

As far as I'm concerned, this should give me some SQL like this:

... WHERE (a.ParentFieldId == NULL) OR (a.ParentFieldId = c.FieldId AND c.Value = parentValue)

But I'm getting a null reference exception. (I assume when the alias is resolved and the Parent is null).

The exception details are:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Criterion.ConstantProjection..ctor(Object value)
       at NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Constant(Object obj)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessSimpleExpression(Expression left, Expression right, ExpressionType nodeType)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessSimpleExpression(BinaryExpression be)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression expression)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessExpression(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessOrExpression(BinaryExpression expression)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression expression)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessExpression(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessLambdaExpression(LambdaExpression expression)
       at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessExpression(Expression`1 expression)
       at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.Add(Expression`1 expression)
       at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.Where(Expression`1 expression)
       at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.NHibernate.IQueryOver<TRoot,TSubType>.Where(Expression`1 expression)
       at Ismoos.Director.FieldOptionsQuery.Execute(Service service, String type, String parentValue) in D:\Work\Ismoos\Ismoos\Director\Ismoos.Director\FieldOptionsQuery.cs:line 31
  InnerException:
```

I've tried a few different ways, including:

```
            .JoinAlias(() => fieldAlias.Parent, () => parentFieldAlias)
            .Where(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.On(() => fieldAlias.Parent).IsNotNull,
                Restrictions.On(() => parentFieldAlias.Value).IsLike(parentValue))))
```

but none of these work.

I have a workaround, by leaving out the restriction on the parent field value in the query, and performing a LINQ query after the QueryOver returns, like so:

```
        Field fieldAlias = null;
        string typeAlias = null;
        Field parentFieldAlias = null;

        var query = getSession().QueryOver<Field>(() => fieldAlias)
            .JoinAlias(() => fieldAlias.Type, () => typeAlias)
            .Where(() => typeAlias.Name == type)
            ;

        var list = query
        .List<Field>()
        ;

        return list
            .Where(x => (x.Parent == null) || (x.Parent.Value == parentValue))
            .ToList();
```

but this isn't as optimal as doing it in the QueryOver.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second solution with restrictions would do the job. There are two issues. We need a LEFT JOIN to Parent and I see a *typo*: `IsNotNull` should be `IsNull` to correctly evaluate the `OR` statement:

Broken solution `IsNotNull` (and most likely inner join)

```
.JoinAlias(() => fieldAlias.Parent, () => parentFieldAlias)
.Where
(
  Restrictions.Or(
    Restrictions.On(() => fieldAlias.Parent).IsNotNull, // here
    Restrictions.On(() => parentFieldAlias.Value).IsLike(parentValue)))
)
```

Working `OR` with `IsNull` and LEFT JOIN:

```
.JoinAlias(() => fieldAlias.Parent, () => parentFieldAlias
           , NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)) // left join for NULL
.Where
(
  Restrictions.Or(
    Restrictions.On(() => fieldAlias.Parent).IsNull, // this is what we need
    Restrictions.On(() => parentFieldAlias.Value).IsLike(parentValue))
);
```

The issue with the first solution is, that we cannot evaluate for null the *floating/virtual object*: *`parentFieldAlias`*

> .Where(() => (parentFieldAlias.Value == parentValue) ||
> *(parentFieldAlias == null)*) ;

We need to check the property of the owner: `fieldAlias.Parent`

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem and additional brackets between conditions

like

```
.Where(() => (parentFieldAlias.Value == parentValue) || (parentFieldAlias == null));
```

get things working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me, after a lot of tests I figured out such solution:

```
query = query.JoinAlias(() => aObject1.Settings, () => aSettings, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
       .Where(Restrictions.IsNull(Projections.Property(() => aSettings.IsVisible)) || 
              Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property(() => aSettings.IsVisible), false));
```

It's creating such SQL query:

```
(aSettings_.IsVisible is null or aSettings_.IsVisible = @pX)
```