# Exception in NHibernate query when use Contains

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have the following classes:

```
class Operation
{
    User User_AssignedTo;
    ResourceGroup ResourceGroup;
} 

class ResourceGroup
{
    List<User> UsersCollection;
}
```

And I have method. It takes user and returns operations. 
Something like that:

```
ResourceGroup resourceGroup = null;

query = conn.Session.QueryOver<Operation>()
        .JoinAlias(item => item.ResourceGroup, () => resourceGroup)
        .Where(item => item.User_AssignedTo.Id == user.Id || resourceGroup.UsersCollection.Contains(userDm));
```

but I have exception

```
Unrecognised method call: System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Mapping.Classes.User, Mapping.Classes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8ab89f53b66a52c3]]:Boolean Contains
```

Comment: I don't NHibernate, but I guess the problem might be that it cannot translate `Contains()` into a SQL query. Could you use something like `resourceGroup.UsersCollection.Any(u => u.ID == userDm.ID)`?

Comment: I tried, but I got same exception, but for Any

Comment: NHibernate doesn't like the '||' operator.  Try this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299022/nhibernate-or-criteria-query][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299022/nhibernate-or-criteria-query

Comment: Can you please show what you tried with `Any()`?

Comment: @Linus: `Any` won't work here. QueryOver is translated into SQL, `.Any` is a method that QueryOver won't know how to convert.

Comment: Can you show the SQL you want to generate with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Contains` is a C# function. In SQL we would use the `MyProperty IN (Select ...)`. To achieve that with NHibernate, to have the IN clause and the inner select - we can use the `DetachedCriteria`:

The documentation: [15.8. Detached queries and subqueries](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries)

There are some detailed examples how to use it:

- [Detailed how to, and advantages of the inner select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16625867/1679310) (e.g. paging)
- [Inner select with group by cluase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654905/1679310)  (e.g. to filter by select Max(id))

NOTE: I would like to provide you with more details even for your solution, some draft.. But the problem is the snippets in the question. To be able to use `IN` both parts should have *some* ID (the 1) ID to selected and 2) the ID to be compared). `ResourceGroup` is missing ID, hard to understand how the *pairing* tables behind are designed.

But at least the DetachedCriteria concept should give you correct direction...

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate doesn't like the '||' operator.  Try this: [NHIbernate OR Criteria Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299022/nhibernate-or-criteria-query)

Another example of how to do an Or operation:
[NHibernate JoinAlias query with null test not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672448/nhibernate-joinalias-query-with-null-test-not-working)

Comment: but how can I use resourceGroup.UsersCollection.Contains(userDm) in this solution?

Comment: Is UsersCollection another table?  if so, you will need another joinalias and join